# Is it true that in the $R$-module $R^k$, the submodules are the ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring and $k$ some positive integer. I would like to show that the submodules of $R^k$ are the ideals. The only issue is that I do not understand how multiplication of two elements in $R^k$ is defined.

For instance, this isn't an issue if $k=1$ because then I can conclude that a submodule of $R^1$ is closed under addition and multiplication which means the same thing as an ideal.

But when $k\geq 2$, can we make the same claim that the submodules of $R^k$ are the ideals?
Thanks.

Comment: The ideals of which ring?

Comment: If you take the ring structure on $R^k$ to be the $k$-fold product ring of $R$ (so e.g. multiplication is componentwise), then this is false.  For example, $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid x = y \}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but not an ideal of the product ring $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Ideals of R^k yes, and I see, I will probably look for another thing then, thanks!